# Qt Set geometry to a newly created widget

Tags: c++, forms, qt, geometry, designer

I have a MainWindow in qt with a Tab Widget attached, containing a tab called "tab_upload". 
On this tab i got a label with the text "Genres" (it's a library application) with a "plus" button attached. I want to be able to get a new QLineEdit every time I click this button , positioned inline with the other ones. To get the right coordonates is easy but I'm not able to properly set the geometry of the new QLineEdit. It doesn't matter what I type in the setGeometry function, the QLineEdit will always appear in the center.
And also, if I press the button a second time I get an error saying

QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QWidget "tab_upload", which already has a layout.

```
 if(nr_genres < 4)
{
    QLineEdit *newgen = new QLineEdit(ui->tab_upload);
    int x = 5 + nr_genres * 90;
    newgen->setGeometry(x,187,90,25);
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(newgen);
    ui->tab_upload->setLayout(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Layouts are designed to [have control](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) over the positioning of widgets:

> All QWidget subclasses can use layouts to manage their children. The QWidget::setLayout() function applies a layout to a widget. When a layout is set on a widget in this way, it takes charge of the following tasks:
>
> - Positioning of child widgets.
> - Sensible default sizes for windows.
> - Sensible minimum sizes for windows.
> - Resize handling.
> - Automatic updates when contents change:
>
>   - Font size, text or other contents of
>     child widgets.
>   - Hiding or showing a child widget.
>   - Removal of child widgets.

You should read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#adding-widgets-to-a-layout) documentation for information about adding widgets to layouts:

> 1. All the widgets will initially be allocated an amount of space in accordance with their QWidget::sizePolicy() and QWidget::sizeHint().
> 2. If any of the widgets have stretch factors set, with a value greater than zero, then they are allocated space in proportion to their stretch factor (explained below).
> 3. If any of the widgets have stretch factors set to zero they will only get more space if no other widgets want the space. Of these, space is allocated to widgets with an Expanding size policy first.
> 4. Any widgets that are allocated less space than their minimum size (or minimum size hint if no minimum size is specified) are allocated this minimum size they require. (Widgets don't have to have a minimum size or minimum size hint in which case the stretch factor is their determining factor.)
> 5. Any widgets that are allocated more space than their maximum size are allocated the maximum size space they require. (Widgets do not have to have a maximum size in which case the stretch factor is their determining factor.)

I think that the easiest way to manage widgets in layouts is to use the Design mode in Qt Creator, and specify a `minimumSize` and/or `maximumSize` for each widget, along with a `sizePolicy`. This way, you can see what happens and experiment with different values.

With regards to the error you're receiving, it is mentioned in the [documentation for `setLayout()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout):

> If there already is a layout manager installed on this widget, QWidget won't let you install another. You must first delete the existing layout manager (returned by layout()) before you can call setLayout() with the new layout.

Answer (score 1):

> QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QWidget
>   "tab_upload", which already has a layout.

You set new layout on widget that already contains layout from previous click on "plus" button. This problem can be solve by next way:

```
QLineEdit *newgen = new QLineEdit(ui->tab_upload);
QVBoxLayout *layout = static_cast<QVBoxLayout*>(ui->tab_upload->layout());
if(!layout) {
    layout = new QVBoxLayout(ui->tab_upload);
    ui->tab_upload->setLayout(layout);
}
layout->addWidget(newgen);
```

But you cannot directly set geometry for your `QLineEdit` because geometry was set by layout. If I understand the problem, this code must help you. It creates new `QLineEdit` after each click on "plus" button and append `QLineEdit` to existing layout.